# How to resolve Authentication session problem?

Tags: laravel

```
$customer = Customer::find(6);
        Auth::login($customer);
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return Auth::user()->name;
        }
```

It's return user name but auth session not work because when redirect another page I can't find auth user any body please help

Working perfect for User instance

```
$user= User::find(6);
        Auth::login($user);
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return Auth::user()->name;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a new user provider for Customer in your `config/auth.php` file:

```
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'customers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Customer::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
```

then define a new guard for your User provider

```
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'web-customer' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'customers',
        ],
    ],
```

then add the Authenticatable trait to your Customer model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;

class Customer extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
     //...
}
```

Finally, you will be able to login using:

```
        $customer = Customer::find(6);
        Auth::guard('web-customer')->login($customer);
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return Auth::user()->name;
        }
```

Comment: Christophe Hubert Thank You for your replay I found another way

Comment: Please add your solution to this page so it can helps other as well 

Comment: `<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Customer extends Authenticatable
{

}`

Comment: well, this is the same as my answer - if you believe it helped you just accept my answer so it can helps others

Comment: yes this is same as your answer but extends model returns error

`class Customer extends Model implements Authenticatable`